# How to check if input string is in between two sets of strings in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex, database

I have a table in MySQL similar to the following:

```
    [id]  [from]    [to]         [input]
    1     AC1.G72   AZ999.M6     AB45.632
    2     B72.F4    B131.D3V.5   B80.F5
    3     B131.E2   B243.G66     B232.G3
```

What I want to do is check if [input] is in between [from] and [to]. So for id=1, it would return false because AB45.632 is not in between AC1.G72-AZ999.M6 and for id=2 and id=3 it would return true. Is it possible to make a check like that in MySQL? If so, what would be the most efficient query? Does there also exist a function in PHP where I can check if a string is within the range of two strings?

Comment: NO, you can't check for between cause those are `varchar` column

Comment: Based on the table above, I just ran a query "SELECT from FROM table WHERE from BETWEEN 'A' and 'AD'" It successfully returned me AC1.G72, so why is it not possible to use between for varchar?

Comment: Do you know what alphabetic order is? I suggest you'll check id=2

Comment: I don't know what you mean by this. If I look at id=2, B80 is between B72 and B131, no? I'm writing a code to separate the strings before and after the '.' I'm merely asking if there's a query that can distinguish if a certain string is between another two strings. It's my fault for poorly wording and giving such a complicated example in my question. I should have just asked if I can check if 'AC' is between 'AA' and 'AE'. Anyways, the answer below is able to achieve what I need for now. And why downvote for asking if something is possible to do in MySQL?

Comment: No. 80 (number) is between 72 and 131 but '80' (text) is not between '72' and '131' since alphabetically '1' comes before '8' and therefore '131' comes before '80'. Run this: `select 80 between 72 and 131 as_number,'80' between '72' and '131' as_text`. So, no. The answer below does not return true for id=2 as you requested. Run this: `select 'B80.F5' between 'B72.F4' and 'B131.D3V.5' for_id_2`.Until now it is not clear how do you compare the columns. Only the numerical part of the first token? Should a different prefix (other than 'B') it impact the comparison? what if the 1st token is equal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "between", but the SQL operator `between` works just fine on string columns in all databases.

So, you can do:

```
select t.*
from t
where 'AB45.632' not between `from` and `to`;
```

This does a strict alphabetic comparison, based on the collation rules for the column, table, database, and server connection.

Comment: I'm using MySQL so the query is a bit different, but this operator actually worked perfectly. Thank you!